# Unable to create system partition or locate existing system partition during Windows-7 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, upgrade

I have Windows XP 32-bit installed on an **ASUS A8N-SLI Deluxe** with 2x 500gb drives in **RAID1** using the **NV RAID** controller. On this there are 3 partitions (XP, XP backup and DATA) There are also 4x 500gb drives in **RAID10** using the Silicon Image 3114R RAID controller.

I just purchased a Windows 7 64-bit as an ISO download **upgrade** version which I promptly burned to DVD and attempted to perform an upgrade installation. Here is the error message I am getting:

[image: Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing partition.]

Firstly, where are these *"Setup log files"* located?

Second, does this mean I need to find compatible (64-bit?) drivers for the Mainboard and put them on floppy?

**EDIT**:
As suggested on another forum, I tried downloading the nVidia Mainboard RAID drivers for Windows 2003 64-bit. I loaded the drivers successfully using the **Load Driver** button, but pressing NEXT still returns this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have mentioned that I have **2** RAID arrays (on both Mainboard controllers) configured. After reading around forums some more, I finally came across an answer that worked:

> Disconnect **ALL** drives (USB, HDD, card-readers, etc.) before starting the installation.

Apparently in my case, the 2nd set of (RAID) drives was messing with Windows Setup. I just unplugged the SATA cables from the drives and installation worked without any errors.

**Update:**
After the installation was almost finished I was asked for my license key, which I inputted but Windows rejected. I found out that I because I formatted the main XP partition, the installer was unable to find a previous XP installation. *Couldn't they just ask for the original XP CD and key? :(*

Lesson learned? **If you are upgrading from XP to 7 using the *Upgrade* DVD, don't format your XP drive!** Windows 7 will rename your old Windows for you. Just make sure to use the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) tool to backup users first.

I had to re-install XP, which was even more difficult as I had to load the NV-RAID drivers onto floppy using the special *MAKEDISK.exe* tool. Then, because I formatted the 1st and 2nd partitions, the 3rd partition became partition #1 -> C: which after the 1st reboot (during install) I got some error about not finding the boot drive (not NTLDR, the other one ;). I then proceeded to back everything up to a USB drive using Ubuntu-on-a-stick which took forever (4+ hours). Afterwards I was able to delete all partitions and create a new one as the first. **phew**

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade usually works better when you start it after booting XP, from XP.

See [Upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7).

**EDIT**

Since you indicated that you are upgrading from 32-bit XP to 64-bit Windows 7, this is a totally new installation, where you cannot keep any of your old programs or system settings.

The procedure to follow in this case seems to be in the [NVIDIA RAID Installation Guide](http://download.asrock.com/manual/raid/N68C-S%20UCC/English.pdf). It does mention an "ASRock Support CD", so I hope that this has something to do with your computer.

Comment: Doesn't work. It says it's not a supported version i.e. can't install 64-bit from within 32-bit XP.

Comment: Added some more stuff.

Comment: I found the answer through another forum, but thanks, it's a good document to have anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an upgrade installation from a 32 bit version of Windows to a 64 bit edition. Just doesn't work. Just do a "custom install" (that is, a simple "fresh" installation) and you'll be fine. You also can't upgrade Windows XP to Windows 7. (Source: [MS TechNet: Windows 7 upgrade paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx))

Please bear in mind that upgrade licenses do not require upgrade installations! An upgrade license doesn't mean you have to do an upgrade installation.

Comment: You had me quite upset for a moment! Then I went back to the EU store page (http://emea.microsoftstore.com/europe/en-US/Microsoft/Windows/Windows-7) which states: "All Windows XP and Windows Vista products qualify for a Windows 7 upgrade."

Comment: Like I said, they qualify for an upgrade license, but not for an upgrade installation.

Comment: What's the difference? Is not 1 license equivalent to 1 installation? Or do you mean I have to use different ISO images?

Comment: The difference is:

Comment: The point is: You don't have to do an upgrade installation just because you have an upgrade license.

Comment: Ok I tried a Custom Install and still getting the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you try to format the partition first (in the same menu)?

Comment: I did, but that led to other problems due to having multiple partitions. I solved this myself last night I'll post the answer.